# Cannot mount DVD "helper failed with: mount: mount point /media/cdrom/ does not exist"

Tags: mount, dvd

I get this error, when trying to play a DVD.

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: mount point /media/cdrom/ does not exist
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu** are you using? (eg. 12.04, 13.04, 13.10) *Is this a CD (in DVD drive), or a DVD, you are trying to play?*

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that mount points which were previously working no longer exist or work (like `/cdrom`) after upgrade to 13.10. Your first optical disk drive (short ODD) should be `/dev/sr0` and `/media/cdrom/`, `/cdrom`, `/dev/cdrom`, `/dev/dvd` etc are just symbolic links to the device file mentioned first. However DVDs and CDs should still be mounted with their label as the mount point in `/media` or `/media/$USER`.

If something is odd, like the USB ROM storage of a USB modem got assigned as your first ODD, or you just want to customize, you can edit lines or remove all lines after the initial comment in the corresponding udev rule, which can be edited viaowing command from terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules
```

Changes apply after reboot, as well as does reconfiguration.